# Which technology to use for high availability application in azure

Tags: virtual-machine, c#, azure

I need to host a C# ASP.NET app / windows service on azure.  However I need the service to run 24/7 and be extremely reliable.

In the past I used to just run it on a vm as a windows service, however I see that azure will just randomly reboot your VM's when they feel like updating it and there's not much you can do about this.

So if I was to go that route I would have to redesign my app to be horizontally scalable, then get two or more VM's and add them to an availability set. Then have to get a load balancer which will split traffic between the two vms?

This seems a bit overkill especially now while my app can indeed scale vertically?

Is there no, headless (Windows Service as a Service) if that makes any sense.

I just need a high level VM that can run my app in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to host a C# ASP.NET app / windows service on azure. However I
>   need the service to run 24/7 and be extremely reliable.

Then you definitely need to deploy your application on several VMs and use load balancer to redistribute the requests. If your application is hosted on a single VM and it crashes for any reason, during the period of fixing this VM, your service suffers a long downtime.

In addition to HA, the load balancer will also bring you the flexible capacity.

Here is good [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/) about Azure load balancer, it might be helpful.

======================================

Update

If you are able to deploy your application on Azure Web App, then it is better than VM. Because MS will takes care of the OS and runtime environment for you. You can focus on your application. For HA with Azure Web App, please refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-web-apps-multi-region/).

Comment: SO how does this differ to a cloud service? Would that not suit me better?

Comment: @Zapnologica Of course, the Azure Web App is better. Because you do not need to take care about the OS and runtime environment, Microsoft will.

Comment: But then I cant run a windows service. Has to be a web app.

Comment: @Zapnologica, that's the reason I said "If you are able to deploy your application on Azure Web App". Besides, actually the cloud services is a container. It can not provide services by itself. The services are still hosted on VMs and Web Apps.